What is the different for "ip\user1" and "server1\user1"?
May I know what's the different for "ip1\user1" and "server1\user1"?
Cause I face a problem when connect remote desktop (RDP) with this 2 different user.
eg. The server name (server1) with ip (IP1), it have a local user (user1).
when I rdp to the ip1 or server1.
with IP1\USER1 fail, NLA error.
with SERVER1\USER  pass.
RDP with just user1 to server1/ip1 also NLA error.

and this is domain join server, just we are using local user for RDP.


The syntax is domain\user. For Active Directory accounts, 'domain' is the NT domain name, while for local accounts it must be the server's hostname i.e. the "computer name".
IP addresses are not valid as NT domain names, so IP1\USER1 doesn't make sense.

i see. Thank you
